# Value's not visible when importing CSV after values are added by fputcsv with php

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I'm trying to make a translation module for my web project and i hit a wall. I written two functions, one for importing the CSV data and the other for changing, deleting and adding new data to the CSV file.

Everything works like a charm except the adding part. It adds the data to the CSV file but when i want to import it in the website via PHP it doesn't display the added values. (It see that their should be values but it gives empty results in return) the function i use for reading the csv file is:

```
// Load in CSV (File name, delimiter, Fixed array[key,value] (optional))
function load__CSV($filename='', $delimiter=';', $fixed = null){
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            } else {
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    if($fixed != null) {
        foreach($data as $entry){
            $set_csv[$entry[''.$fixed[0].'']] = $entry[''.$fixed[1].''];
        }
    } else {
        $set_csv = $data;
    }

    return $set_csv;
}
```

The function i use to add, edit or remove CSV content is:

```
// Change csv
function update__csv($csv = 'csv/language.csv',$key = array(2,''),$values = array([3,''],[4,'']),$status = 'change') {
    $input = fopen(BASE_URL.$csv, 'r');
    $output = fopen(BASE_URL.'csv/temporary.csv', 'w');

    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($input, 10000, ";"))) {
        if ($data[$key[0]] == $key[1]) {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $data[$value[0]] = $value[1];
            }
            if ($status == 'change' || $status == 'new') {
                fputcsv($output, $data, ";");
            }
        } else {
            fputcsv($output, $data, ";");
        }
    }

    if($status == 'new'){
        fputcsv($output, $values, ";");
    }

    fclose( $input );
    fclose( $output );

    unlink(BASE_URL . $csv);
    rename(BASE_URL . 'csv/temporary.csv', BASE_URL . $csv);
}
```

If i add new values to the CSV file and then open the CSV on my PC and safe it again (without changing a thing) to CSV with UTF-8 encoding then it works as expected and loads the correct data. If i open the CSV in Notepad++ i see this difference between manual added items and php added items:
[image]

I tried other encoding methods but that is kinda new for me so i think i did something wrong. Thank you in advance for helping me!

Comment: I have no clue what is actually supposed to be wrong here, and your screenshot doesn’t help. You put a wriggly red line under part of the data - and that is supposed to tell us what now?

Comment: I'm sorry your right. The screenshot is from Notepad++ where the code under the wriggly red line is added (i think when you save the CSV manually). But if you put a new row of data into the CSV file with 'fputcsv' in PHP it doesn't at the part with the wriggly line. If i add that part manually and save the file then de data reads like it should. The two functions given works but the only problem i have is that the added data with 'fputcsv' is not visible while loading in the CSV with PHP.

Comment: If `fputcsv` writes less columns than expected, then the most logical conclusion is that you filled your data array that you are passing to it, with too little values to begin with … so, debug a bit?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i did some debug (i also tried something just now) and it is indeed extra coloms. But when i originaly made the CSV file their where only 5 coloms. It is only when i use 'fputcsv' for adding new values (so not for removing or editing values) it adds 2 extra coloms. I don't get why it does this. I found nothing in the code that explains why it adds those extra coloms.

Comment: `fputcsv` creates as many columns in one output line, as the array you are feeding it contains elements.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer after some more debugging. One value of the array didn't contain a string but a true or false statement. This meant that it didn't add the data the right way into the CSV file.

I fixed it by adding `strval()` to every variable before putting it into an array.